# imap_delete() not working?

Tags: php, imap

I'm making a bounce handler, and I want to delete all of the bounced emails. I'm trying to do it with `imap_delete()`, but the emails are not deleted. What could be the problem?

```
<?php
// Settings
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/settings.php');

// Bounce
$bounce = array();

$inbox = imap_open('{imap.example.com:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'mail-bounce@example.com', 'SECRET') or die('Cannot connect to mailbox: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');

if($emails) {
    foreach($emails as $id) {
        preg_match('/<(.*?)>: host/s', imap_fetchbody($inbox, $id, 1), $matches);

        $bounce[] = $matches[1];

        imap_delete($inbox, $id);
    }
}

imap_close($inbox);

if(!empty($bounce)) {
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE newsletter SET status=-1 WHERE email='" . implode(" OR email='", $bounce) . "'");
    $STH->execute();
}
?>
```

`imap_last_error()` doesn't return any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`imap_delete()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-delete.php) marks the email for deletion.  But it's not actually deleted until you call [`imap_expunge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-expunge.php), or until you call [`imap_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-close.php) with the optional `CL_EXPUNGE` parameter.

Comment: Ha, I've missed that! It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot!